# Using expression instead of string in Type: Template format error: [/Resources/EKS] Every Type member must be a string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

Can you help me please?
I am trying to use CloudFormation with extensions

```
  EKSClusterExtension:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::TypeActivation
    Properties:
      AutoUpdate: false
      TypeNameAlias:  !Sub "EKS::Cluster::${EnvironmentName}"
     
  EKS:
    Type: !Sub "EKS::Cluster::${EnvironmentName}"
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref EnvironmentName
      RoleArn: !GetAtt Kubernetes.Arn
```

and have error message:

`Template format error: [/Resources/EKS] Every Type member must be a string.`

How can i resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear: "Every Type member must be a string". You **can't dynamically set type**. You must hardcode its value, e.g.;

```
Type: "EKS::Cluster::MyEnv"
```

Comment: What can I do if I need to run few stacks automatically? Possible do you know better way?

Comment: @VladimirTselm You could create your own [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) which would transform your cloudformation template to automatically expand your resources.